# Calling a changing function name on an object with PHP : how?

Tags: php

How would I do something like this :

```
class Test
{

    public function test($methodName) {
        $this->$methodName;
    }

    private function a() {
        echo("a");
    }

    private function b() {
        echo("b");
    }

}

$testObj = new Test();
$testObj->test("a()");
$testObj->test("b()");
```

Maybe I should just pass a parameter "TYPE" and use a "IF statement" but I'm just curious! :)

And what if the "dynamic function name" has one or more parameters?

UPDATE : Thanks everyone! :)

**UPDATE #2 - Answer :**

```
class Test
{

    public function testOut($methodName) {
        $this->$methodName();
    }

    private function a() {
        echo("a");
    }

    private function b() {
        echo("b");
    }

}

$testObj = new Test();
$testObj->testOut("a");
$testObj->testOut("b");
```

The problem with the class is that there was a method named "Test" (the same as the class name)... I changed it and it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Test
{

    public function test($methodName) {
        $this->$methodName();
    }

    private function a() {
        echo("a");
    }

    private function b() {
        echo("b");
    }

}

$testObj = new Test();
$testObj->test("a");
$testObj->test("b");
```

Comment: The method name was the "constructor" because it was the same name as the class, so that's why it didn't work I think. I posted an update with your code, only changing the method "test" for "testOut"

Comment: U R right, been some time since I used CPP,C# and other OOP languages where there is no __construct

Answer (score 1):

Check out `call_user_func()` - it should do what you want.

[Documentation here](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)

Answer (score 1):

**[call_user_func](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)** allows you to do things like this.

For example,

```
funcname = 'a';
call_user_func(array($testObj, $funcname));
```

The other alternative is to use **[variable methods](http://php.mirrors.ilisys.com.au/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)**

For example,

```
$funcname = 'a';
$testObj->$funcname();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a "dynamic function name" with more than one parameter, you can use call_user_func_array, like this:

```
//in class context..
//$parameters can be an array like array(1,2)
call_user_func_array(array($this, $methodName), $parameters);
```

The reason you would want to use call_user_func_array instead of call_user_func is that you can pass the parameters the function takes as an array, instead of just as additional parameters, thus allowing you to easily have a variable number of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Following your particular example and use case, the only way to achieve this exactly:

```
$testObj = new Test();
$testObj->test("a()");
$testObj->test("b()");
```

would be to use [eval()](http://www.php.net/eval):

```
class Test
{

    public function test($methodName) {
        eval($methodName);
    }

    private function a() {
        echo("a");
    }

    private function b() {
        echo("b");
    }

}

$testObj = new Test();
$testObj->test("a()");
$testObj->test("b()");
```

Others pointed out a solution using [`call_user_func()`](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) and rightly so. Also evidently, is faster than using eval() for function calls. Read this:

http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php#64415

Comment: Why does pointing out another way to do something, with an example and  some good reading get an immediate downvote without explanation?